# php form with FPDF and file uploads

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a FPDF script that is working fine but i would like to create a folder using the 'name' post data as the folder name and put the pdf into it.

Right now it just moves it to the claims folder but i would like it to go to /claims/$name/$name.pdf

basically it must create another directory folder within /claims/ using the $name data.

anything i try i get "page cannot be displayed"

my current fpdf output:

```
$filename = "claims/$name.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
header('Location: home.php');
```

Comment: the answer looks to be in your question `claims/$name/$name.pdf`

Comment: @rtfm tried that sir i get a error.This page isnt working

Comment: "This page isnt working " is an error from what? you did create the $name directory first?

Comment: i dont know @rtfm i only get site is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: normally it takes me to home.php and the file is moved.

Comment: @rtfm i would like it to make a new directory every time someone with a new name submits a form.

Comment: it? your code needs to make the dir: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @rtfm got it working thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

as @rtfm assisted me in pointing me in the right direction.

this is the now working code:

```
mkdir("claims/$name", 0777);
$filename = "claims/$name/$name.pdf";

$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
header('Location: home.php');
```